# Dynamically changing the SlickGrid cell styles

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

```
grid.setCellCssStyles("birthday_highlight", {
    0: {
        birthday: "highlight", 
        age: "highlight" 
    },

    9: {
        birthday: "highlight",
        age: "highlight"
    }
})
```

In the above code instead 0 & 9 numbers can we pass any dynamic variable i.e., if I want to change the style of any cell by clicking on that particular cell, is it possible to change the particular cell styles?

Answer (score 1):

It is not about `Slickgrid`, it is about `JS` - create an object and pass it to `setCellCssStyles`:

```
var cellStyle = {};

cellStyle[rowNum] = {}; // <- your particular cell in a row with number rowNum
cellStyle[rowNum]["birthday"] = "highlight";
grid.setCellCssStyles("birthday_highlight", cellStyle);
```